# How to resolve "Service status is healthy, but test call return 'BadGateway'" error in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: deployment, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Designer in Azure ML studio to build a prediction model. I keep getting the following error: "Deploy: Service status is healthy, but test call return 'BadGateway'" when I deploy a real-time inference of the model, even after using the designer model structure from the Diabetes tutorial. The model publishes and deploys "successfully" (endpoint and keys are created) but it can't be consumed.

How can I resolve this issue?